# c wrapper from c++ , namespaced enums

Tags: c++, enums, wrapper, d

I'm trying to get OIS work with D. I'm making an OIS wrapper from C++ to C to D.
The problem is, I have to pass an `OIS::KeyCode` enum to C, but I don't know how. I could just copy it but it seems to me much more sane not copying it.

EDIT: OIS has MouseButtonID and KeyCode, both of them are in the OIS namespace, how do I translate that into C for passing it later to D?

Comment: can you post any code examples? My first thought is instead of passing an enum, just pass it as an int. But I've never used OIS before so I'm not sure what exactly is going on here.

Comment: I think now it's better explained, but it's just that, how I can pass a enum which is inside a namespace to C, and later to D.

Comment: you should match the type and value (and cast where necessary), I think the linker can deal with that pretty well

Answer (score 0):

Did you try casting the enum to int?